# System.OutOfMemoryException when invoking Dapper's QueryAsync<>() method

Tags: c#, memory, out-of-memory, dapper

#### My problem

In my logs I've seen some System.OutOfMemoryException errors logged during load tests. They're coming from a Dapper query. Based on the stacktrace, the error is happening when the list is resized.

#### Top of stacktrace

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value) at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddWithResize(T item)
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync[T](IDbConnection cnn, Type effectiveType, CommandDefinition command) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 442

#### The code being invoked

```
const string sql = $@"
  SELECT [Column 1]
        ,[Column 2]
        ,[Column 3]
        ,[Column 4]
        ,[Column 5]
        ,[Column 6]
        ,[Column 7]
        ,[Column 8]
        ,[Column 9]
        ,[Column 10]
        ,[Column 11]
        ,[Column 12]
    FROM [MyDb].[MyTable]
    WHERE co = @CompanyId AND process = @Process
    ";

await using var connection = _dbConnectionProvider.Create(DbKey.MyDb);

var parameters = new { CompanyId = CompanyDbString(companyId), Process = process };
var command = new CommandDefinition(sql, parameters);
var results = await connection.QueryAsync<MyEntity>(command); // error happens here

return results;
```

#### Some info about the data being loaded

I looked at the database, and saw that the data in question is 141,846 rows in size. The columns are nothing "out of the ordinary" (no giant text blobs or anything like that), just some reasonable varchars, datetimes, ints, etc. All the varchars max out at 100 chars.

And just to nip the inevitable "Do you really need to load all that data?" comment in the bud: Yes I do.

#### Possible solution?

So, the data being loaded is a pretty large dataset, but nothing *too* crazy. I was surprised it ran out of memory. What I find particularly interesting is that the exception stemmed from `System.Collections.Generic.List1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)`. Based on that, it looks like the error happened while the list was resizing its internal array.

My first thought on how to approach this was to page the result, kind of how its suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212051

However, I'm not sure if that'll work since it still relies on a list being added to. Is that a valid concern? If so, would getting the count first and starting the list with that as the initial capacity be a good approach?

Or is there maybe a different collection that is more resize/memory friendly than List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do an [unbuffered Dapper query](https://www.learndapper.com/misc/buffered-unbuffered), and insert the results into a pre-sized list.

```cs
var list = new List<MyEntity>(someBigSizeHere);
var command = new CommandDefinition(sql, parameters) { Buffered = false };
using var results = await connection.QueryAsync<MyEntity>(command);
list.AddRange(results);
return list;
```

Note that you must make sure to fully read *and dispose* the `results` before closing the connection.

If you are still getting out of memory exceptions after this, then you simply do not have enough for the data. Try compiling to 64-bit and adding more RAM to your system. Or better: rethink why you want so much data.